# Use downloadHandler to edit an existing excel file based on uploaded data?

Tags: r, excel, download, shiny

I am working on a shiny app where the user will upload an excel file, the data will be manipulated, and then a new excel file with this data is exported for the user to examine. I am having issues with the downloadHandler function. I used to create an entirely new excel file every time based on the uploaded data like this:

```
output$export <- downloadHandler(
filename = "answers.xlsx",
content = function(file){
  write.xlsx(exportdata(), file)
     })
  })
```

This works fine.

Now I would like to edit an excel file that I will include when I publish the app and allow the user to download this edited version like this:

```
output$export <- downloadHandler(
filename = "answers.xlsx",
content = function(file){
  wb <- loadWorkbook("6rep-charts.xlsx")
  writeData(wb, sheet = "Species Match Results", correlInput())
  writeData(wb, sheet = "BS1 Data", bs1Input())
  writeData(wb, sheet = "BS2 Data", bs2Input())
  saveWorkbook(wb, file)
})
```

However, this results in the error `Warning: Error in write_file: Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=0]. [No stack trace available]`. I am not sure what is going wrong as when I run the content section outside of the shiny app, it works just fine. The problem seems to be in the `saveWorkbook` command.

The reason I would like to edit an existing excel file rather than create a new one is that the template file I'm including in the app has charts already made that should change when the new data is written into the file. The users would like to be able to edit these charts themselves, rather than just see a picture of a graph. If anyone has a simpler way to accomplish this, that would be great! Thank you in advance for your help!

Reproducible example using [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R5-AMNjqkXooQOi2BHKsda_jjfxiP1AvFLPm-7SJvCg/edit?usp=sharing) excel file:

```
    library(shiny); library(readxl); library(xlsx)
    ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
    fluidRow(
       column(3,
          downloadButton(outputId = "export",
               label = "Export Results to Excel")
  ),

       column(6,
         dataTableOutput("data")
  ))))

    server <- function(input, output) {
       adata <- faithful[1:20,]   
       bdata <- faithful[21:50,]   
       cdata <- faithful[51:200,]

   read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename, tibble = FALSE) {
      sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
      x <- lapply(sheets, function(Y) {readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = Y)})
      if(!tibble) x <- lapply(x, as.data.frame)
      names(x) <- sheets
      x
   }

   output$data <- renderDataTable({
       adata   })

   output$export <- downloadHandler(
       filename = "answers.xlsx",
       content = function(file){
          wb <- loadWorkbook("./Data/template.xlsx")
          writeData(wb, sheet = "Alpha", adata)
          writeData(wb, sheet = "Beta", bdata)
          writeData(wb, sheet = "Gamma", cdata)
          saveWorkbook(wb, file="./Data/temp.xlsx", overwrite = T)
          print("done")
          Fin_WB<- read_excel_allsheets("./Data/temp.xlsx")
          write.xlsx(Fin_WB, file)
        }   ) }

   shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643888/how-do-i-append-data-from-a-data-frame-in-r-to-an-excel-sheet-that-already-exist

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46938075/unable-to-append-r-data-frame-into-existing-excel-without-overwriting?rq=1

Comment: Maybe append the file outside of the content function, and then just write the file inside the download handler?

Comment: I would also ensure the application is able to access the workbook, as sometimes when publishing data along with an app, a separate data directory needs to be specified and used in the data path. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793616/how-to-deploy-shiny-app-that-uses-local-data

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Chabo, I've added an example that might explain what's going on. I think the problem has to do with the `saveWorkbook` function, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: What package are the `Workbook` functions under?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `saveWorkbook` function does not like to operate as a write function for the `content` function. Confusing yes, but we can still use it within the content function, just not as the final step. We have to use a classic write function such as `write.xlsx` to satisfy the content function which is expecting the file and file path to write to.

To get around this we create a temp file in the Data folder (this *folder* will be in the dir with server and ui, and will be published). The program reads in the template file (see special function below), modifies it, and then writes/overwrites the **temp** file. This temp file is then read in and assigned by `read.xlsx` and then written to by `write.xlsx`. This satisfies the content function and allows us to use a template for export.

```
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename, tibble = FALSE) {
    sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
    x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X))
    if(!tibble) x <- lapply(x, as.data.frame)
    names(x) <- sheets
    x
  }

output$export <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "answers.xlsx",
    content = function(file){
      wb <- loadWorkbook("./Data/template.xlsx")
      writeData(wb, sheet = "Alpha", adata)
      writeData(wb, sheet = "Beta", bdata)
      writeData(wb, sheet = "Gamma", cdata)
      saveWorkbook(wb, file="./Data/temp.xlsx", overwrite = T)
      print("done")
      Fin_WB<- read_excel_allsheets("./Data/temp.xlsx")
      write.xlsx(Fin_WB, file)
    }) 
  }
```

In order to read in all the sheets, we cannot simply use `read.xlsx` as it wont look at all the sheets. Using a function created [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945687/read-all-worksheets-in-an-excel-workbook-into-an-r-list-with-data-frames) by Jeromy Anglim, we can read in all the sheets from excel. This is the `read_excel_allsheets` function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I have tried what you suggested - creating a data folder containing the template.xlsx file and a new temp.xlsx file, adding the `read_excel_allsheets` function, and adjusting the `content` function - but still get the `Error in write_file: Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=0].` error. Any thoughts on why that is? I've updated the question to include the whole current code.

Comment: @Zoe Bleicher Make sure you have installed and are using `library(openxlsx)`

Comment: After inserting `library(openxlsx)` to your code the program worked as expected. Note that the download handler works better when used in the browser (correct filename & type), so test it there. If the program still does not work ensure the Data folder is in the project directory or whatever directory the server and UI are in. You can also try to open and re-save the excel file, sometimes excel is strange.

Comment: Opening and re-saving the excel files did the trick. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Simpler solution (I am unable to leave comments due to too low reputation):

```
output$export <- downloadHandler(
filename = "answers.xlsx",
content = function(file){
  wb <- loadWorkbook("./Data/template.xlsx")
  writeData(wb, sheet = "Alpha", adata)
  writeData(wb, sheet = "Beta", bdata)
  writeData(wb, sheet = "Gamma", cdata)
  saveWorkbook(wb, file="./Data/temp.xlsx", overwrite = T)
  file.copy(from = "./Data/temp.xlsx", to = file)
})
```

No need for the function *read_excel_allsheets*.