# Cannot insert R dataframe into an existing Excel file without overwriting

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, rstudio

I am trying to insert an R `dataframe` from Rstudio to an already existing Excel sheet without overwriting the entire file. I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46938075/unable-to-append-r-data-frame-into-existing-excel-without-overwriting) solution, but the instruction `loadWorkbook` gives me this error:

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl, : org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

With this traceback:

```
6.
stop(structure(list(message = "org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException", call = .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl, .jcast(if (inherits(o, "jobjRef") || inherits(o, "jarrayRef")) o else cl, "java/lang/Object"), .jnew("java/lang/String", ...
5.
.jcheck(silent = FALSE)
4.
.jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl, .jcast(if (inherits(o, "jobjRef") || inherits(o, "jarrayRef")) o else cl, "java/lang/Object"), .jnew("java/lang/String", method), j_p, j_pc, use.true.class = TRUE, evalString = simplify, ...
3.
.jrcall(x, name, ...)
2.
wbFactory$create(inputStream)
1.
loadWorkbook("Recon Metro Fuels JR B VN Ene 2019 V2.xlsx")
```

I am using the libraries:

- `pdftools`, for extracting text from a PDF.
- `openxlsx`& `xlsx`, for Excel manipulation.
- `dplyr`, for the `%>%` operator.

For more information about the Excel, Size: `29MB`, is in .xlsx file format.

Here is the code on how i'm doing it:

```
#load exel file
old_data<- readWorkbook("Recon Metro Fuels JR B VN Ene 2019 V2.xlsx", sheet = "Raw BAC VN CON FIREFOX");
#Combines the Excel sheet with the new updated sheet
new_data<-bind_rows(old_data, pdf_refined);

wb<- loadWorkbook("Recon Metro Fuels JR B VN Ene 2019 V2.xlsx")
```

What causes this error? 
Are there other ways to do it?

Comment: Which package are you using to handle excel files? The mentioning of java in the error makes me think it's `XLConnect` which is somewhat notorious for its java dependency... I eventually gave up on it and switched to `openxlsx`. Never looked back (except once where I had to deal with an '.xls' file...)

Comment: @dario I am using openxlsx and xlsx, to handle my Excel file. I also updated the post with the libraries I am using.

Comment: then it must be 'xlsx'. I'd suggest avoiding it and using `openxlsx` only. Is there a reason you load both libraries 'xlsx' **and** 'openxlsx'?

Comment: @dario Thanks, I do not remember why I'd used that library, removing it resolved the error. But Rsutdio reported another error, I don't know if I should update the question or write the problem in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a conflict with the libraries:`openxlsx` & `xlsx`.

So in the end I Removed `xlsx`.